Regex grafana variable
I am using grafana variables to bring some data, but the data comes with '%20' that I need to remove using regex, I have tried many times without result, the data has this form:
PSM%20APP%20ST%20
PSM%20AV
PSM%20High%20Ase
PSM%20Ate

I want to remove all appearances of %20, it should look like this:
PSM APP ST
PSM AV
PSM Alta Ase
PSM Ate

Please, who can help me solve? Thank you.

What's the problem? s/%20/ /g?

This is URL encoding. Most languages have a function for decoding, e.g. urldecode() in PHP.

I tried it, it doesn't work in grafana variables

Please show how you tried to use it.

/.%20([^%])./
/.%20([^%])./
/.([^"])./
(.).%20(.)
None of that has worked. It is for grafana variables.

Edit the question to add a [mre] showing the code.

You've said "grafana variables" multiple times, there's no need to repeat it. I don't actually know grafana, I don't know why it would make a difference.

I think regular expressions don't work correctly in grafana

Try: \u002520 or \\u002520 or \\%20 and replace it with an empty string ' ' ?

Grafana's regex functionality for variables only works for filtering and extraction.
Other manipulations, like replacement, are not supported.
Since here all desired data cannot be extracted into a single group, regex is not something what can solve your problem. You need to modify your data on the data source level, or use chained variables to create new variable based on the existing one.
